# Programmatically added taxonomy terms not being indexed

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm assigning taxonomy terms to an entity (user) like this:

`$drupalUser->taxonomy_vocabulary_6 = array('und' => array(0 => array('tid' => _findorcreate_tid($eecid, $arrUser[12]))));`

`_findorcreate_tid` finds, or creates a new tid, within the supplied vocabulary.  This function is working correctly. **$eecid** is the vocabulary ID. **$arrUser** is some user data imported from a CSV.

When viewing the user object, the correct term name and ID is displayed, but viewing the term's "contents" (at a URL like http://localhost/taxonomy/term/1061), I'm told there is no content.

My very amateur poking around leads me to believe that the taxonomy_index table is not getting populated when I assign the terms in this manner.

I have tried to call 
`taxonomy_build_node_index($drupalUser);`
after the user object is saved, but this has yielded no change (and I'm a bit unclear if that function only applies to nodes, or any entity).

**Is there a better way of assigning taxonomy terms to a user entity that would fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. The core taxonomy module doesn't index or display entities other than nodes. [`taxonomy_build_node_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_build_node_index/7) is only for nodes.

It sounds like the solution you're looking for is [Taxonomy Entity Index](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_entity_index).

> The Taxonomy Entity Index module maintains a normalized index of all
>   terms associated with a specific entity and revision. The core
>   {taxonomy_index} table only maintains its data for published nodes.
>   This module maintains its data for all entity types (regardless of
>   published or not) and also indexed by revision.

It also supports views integration so you should be able to create a view of users who have been tagged with your taxonomy.